# Is there a way to convert a time in nanosecond to a String without the zeroes?

Tags: java, string, time

The expected result is "Last game 2h 12m ago." or "Last game 3m ago.".

Currently it is "Last game 0d 2h 12m ago.", I found nothing in SimpleDateFormat that could do that and the easiest solution I see would be using a StringBuilder, testing whether or not the values are zero each time.

Code sample:

```
public String getLastgame()
{
    long time = ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 60000) - this.config.getLastgameTime());

    return ("Last game " + (time / 60) + "h " + (time % 60) + "m ago.");
}
```

Comment: Show some **code** please !

Comment: `in a nanosecond` depends on your machine ;)

Comment: I could also do something like `(hours == 0) ? (hours + "h") : ""` I guess, but I don't like it very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your time is measured in minutes, so, extract all your time components first:

```
long oneYear = 60 * 24 * 365;
long oneDay = 60 * 24;
long oneHour = 60;

// extract years
int years = time / oneYear;
// update your time
time = time % oneYear;

// extract days
long days = time / oneDay;
// update your time
time = time % oneDay;

// extract hours    
long hours = time / oneHour;

// extract minutes (the remaining)
minutes = time % oneHour;
```

Then, build your String:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "Last time " );
if ( years != 0 ) {
    sb.append( years ).append( "y " );
}
if ( days != 0 ) {
    sb.append( days ).append( "d " );
}
if ( hours != 0 ) {
    sb.append( hours ).append( "h " );
}
if ( minutes != 0 ) {
    sb.append( minutes ).append( "m " );
}
sb.append( " ago" );
```

The complete method will be:

```
public String getLastgame() {

    long time = ((System.currentTimeMillis() / 60000) - this.config.getLastgameTime());

    long oneYear = 60 * 24 * 365;
    long oneDay = 60 * 24;
    long oneHour = 60;

    // extract years
    int years = time / oneYear;
    // update your time
    time = time % oneYear;

    // extract days
    long days = time / oneDay;
    // update your time
    time = time % oneDay;

    // extract hours    
    long hours = time / oneHour;

    // extract minutes (the remaining)
    minutes = time % oneHour;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( "Last time " );
    if ( years != 0 ) {
        sb.append( years ).append( "y " );
    }
    if ( days != 0 ) {
        sb.append( days ).append( "d " );
    }
    if ( hours != 0 ) {
        sb.append( hours ).append( "h " );
    }
    if ( minutes != 0 ) {
        sb.append( minutes ).append( "m " );
    }
    sb.append( " ago" );

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: This is what I was going for, I don't see anything else. This will be used in many places so I'll probably make it into a static method, thanks for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of 'd', 'm' and 'h' in the String. check the value of the characters at index -1 and index-2. If index -2 is a space, check index-1.If it is a 0, remove those indices. And that is 1 way of doing it.

Comment: This seems very wrong, giving that I am building the string, checking and removing values after is not very efficient.